# Get facebook fans count using API 2.8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get Facebook fans count using http request in API 2.8

-- I test these requests but not working

This return an array but no Fans Count

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{APP_ID}?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&edges=fan_count
```

Return

```
{
  "category": "Entertainment",
  "link": {APP LINK},
  "name": {NAME},
  "id": {ID}
}
```

-- This throw an error array

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{APP_ID}?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&fields=likes
```

Return

```
{
  "error": {
     "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (likes) on node type (Application)",
     "type": "OAuthException",
     "code": 100,
     "fbtrace_id": "FlkGoTOJ403"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want pal?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct one:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{PAGE_ID}?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&fields=fan_count
```

Not sure why you would use an App for this, Fans are for Pages.

Comment: {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (fan_count) on node type (Application)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "ABBxrv4WTKE"
   }
}

Comment: please read the last sentence of my answer. apps don´t have a fan_count, as you can read in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/

Answer (score -1):

Use {PAGE_NAME} instead of {APP_ID}

```
GET ACCESS TOKEN: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP_ID}&client_secret={APP_SECRET_KEY}&grant_type=client_credentials

GET FANS COUNT: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{PAGE_NAME}?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&fields=fan_count
```

Thanks for [luschn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757508/luschn)